# Windows batch choice option

Tags: batch-file

I have a windows batch file that look like this:

```
choice /C:123 /n /m "Generate output? (1. Debug only 2. Production only 3. Both debug and production)"
if errorlevel==1 (
    echo 1
)
if errorlevel==2 (
    echo 2
)
if errorlevel==3 (
    echo 3
)
```

The problem is when user select `3`, it will echo out 1, 2 and 3. Which it should only echo `3`. How can I solve it?

Comment: Reverse the choices. `if errorlevel==3... if errorlevel==2...if errolevel==1`.

Comment: @KenWhite Same thing. It just echo in reverse order.

Comment: Use `%errorlevel%` instead of `errorlevel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is in the SomethingDark's comment.
The reason why your script fails is because `=` is a standard delimiter  in batch files (like `<space><tab>;,`) and your conditions take other form of `IF` command different than comparison:

```
IF ERRORLEVEL N execute command
```

Which means - [if errorlevel](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) is equal or bigger than `N` execute the command.[So that's why with 3 all conditions are performed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx).

And for real equality check you need:

```
choice /C:123 /n /m "Generate output? (1. Debug only 2. Production only 3. Both debug and production)"
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (
    echo 1
)
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 (
    echo 2
)
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 (
    echo 3
)
```

Mind that `==` always forces a string comparison and `EQU, NEQ, LSS, LEQ, GTR, GEQ` are the correct switches for numeric comparison (which is not so crucial when you perform equality check )